# Direct Memory Leak in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway to forward requests to backend services. After server runs about 1 or 2 hours, I got direct memory leak detect error logs.

I add **-Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=paranoid -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords=40** and enable the DEBUG logs of **reactor.netty.channel** to get more details.

The following is the log of the server. Hope someone can help me to investigate the issue.

```
-2021-11-23 15:36:33.708 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 ERROR [reactor-http-epoll-4] io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector    - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
#1:
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:285)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
#2:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.forEachByte(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:670)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.parse(HttpObjectDecoder.java:908)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.readTrailingHeaders(HttpObjectDecoder.java:696)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:398)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:225)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
#3:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.forEachByte(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:670)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.parse(HttpObjectDecoder.java:908)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$LineParser.parse(HttpObjectDecoder.java:965)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:350)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:225)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
#4:
    Hint: [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] Buffered ByteBufHolder in Inbound Flux Queue
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.touch(DefaultHttpContent.java:86)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.touch(DefaultHttpContent.java:25)
    reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:366)
    reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:358)
    reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:677)
    reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
#5:
    Hint: 'reactor.right.reactiveBridge' will handle the message from this point.
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.touch(DefaultHttpContent.java:86)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.touch(DefaultHttpContent.java:25)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
#6:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.getByte(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:154)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:388)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:225)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
#7:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.readRetainedSlice(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:106)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:373)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:225)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
#8:
    Hint: 'reactor.left.httpCodec' will handle the message from this point.
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
#9:
    Hint: 'DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext#0' will handle the message from this point.
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:402)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:178)
    io.netty.channel.unix.PreferredDirectByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(PreferredDirectByteBufAllocator.java:53)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator$MaxMessageHandle.allocate(DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator.java:114)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollRecvByteAllocatorHandle.allocate(EpollRecvByteAllocatorHandle.java:75)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:780)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
: 1 leak records were discarded because they were duplicates
```

The only logs with the id *0xd7427df5*

```
-2021-11-23 15:34:40.869 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:34:41.153 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:34:41.706 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:03.010 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:04.510 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:08.338 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:11.380 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:12.172 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:13.463 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:13.749 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:22.467 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:41.516 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:35:49.962 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:09.631 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:10.510 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:11.190 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:15.391 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:15.483 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:24.274 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:25.184 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:28.756 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
    Hint: [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] Buffered ByteBufHolder in Inbound Flux Queue
-2021-11-23 15:36:35.062 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:36.062 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:36.667 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:39.524 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:40.988 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:41.412 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:41.524 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:36:43.821 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:37:03.107 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
-2021-11-23 15:37:03.561 gateway-web-66c9645c84-6v7d8 10.242.167.104 DEBUG [reactor-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive    - [id: 0xd7427df5, L:/10.242.167.104:59588 - R:10.242.166.45/10.242.166.45:10240] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
```

**Framework versions**

- Spring Cloud version: Hoxton.SR12
- Spring boot Version: 2.3.12.RELEASE
- Reactor Netty Version: 0.9.20.RELEASE

Comment: I would take this problem to the developpers (or respectively the bug tracker of the product). The before last thing one wants from software is memory leaks. I would guess that the developpers would be very happy to hear from you and to plug the leak.